# On an equality of (absolute values of) complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, complex-numbers

I was considering about equality of complex numbers, which I was feeling true, but not able to proceed for proof.

Suppose $z_1,z_2,\cdots,z_k$ be comples numbers with $|z_i|=1$. If $|z_1+\cdots+z_k|=k$ then is it necessary that all $z_i$'s are same? It looks to me to be true, but....proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a mere application of the famous *triangle inequality*. And by this inequality, we can say that 
$$|z_1|+|z_2|+|z_3|+\ldots+|z_k| \geq |z_1+z_2+z_3+\ldots +z_k| \tag1$$
where the equality holds if and only if $z_1=z_2=z_3=\ldots=z_k$

And as your problem states,
$$(1) \implies 1+1+1+\ldots+1 =k \geq k$$
So the equality case of the triangle inequality holds and your answer follows from it.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: |1| + |2| = |1+2|, but 1 <> 2.